# JavaScript Check if File exists, if not then

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, if-statement, exists

I am working on a table where I need to return images in the first column.
The below code works fine except if it doesn't find the image then I get an error.

I would like to check if the file exists and if it does not exist, to return a default image. How should I approach this?

Thanks,

```
              Cell: cellProps => {
                const imgPath = cellProps.row.ExternalID;
                return (
                  <img
                    src={require(`../images/${imgPath}.png`)}
                    alt=""
                  />
                );
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onerror` attribute:

```
              <img
                src={require(`../images/${imgPath}.png`)}
                alt=""
                onerror="this.src='../images/default.png'"
              />
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for answering, unfortunately this does not seem to work.. I'm still getting error message that my missing pictures can't be found. I am using react. Would you know why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Maybe react has its own error handler?